# SSE in WSGI without platform

Tags: python, wsgi, server-sent-events

I wish to extend my (raw) WSGI application with SSE. I am not experienced with SSE, and all examples I find use Flask, Tornado, or similar platforms. I would rather not port my application from raw WSGI to one of these platforms, so I would like to know if someone can point me to an example of how to set up the SSE stream with only Python and WSGI ressources, possibly with use of facility packages, but without requiring me to move to a platform.
EDIT: I am currently using Python 2.7 with libapache2-mod-wsgi

Comment: I don't think there's any standard interface for doing such things, so you'll probably need to integrate closer with the web server in one way or another.

Comment: Thanks Dolda2000, I shall go and try it with Flask.